# What are the main distinctions between a chart and a patch?

Tags: differential-geometry

[Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Patch.html) gives this definition of a patch:

> A patch is a differentiable mapping $\vec x: U \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$, where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology)#Charts) gives this definition of a chart:

> A chart for a topological space $M$ is a homeomorphism $\phi$ from an open subset $U$ of $M$ to an open subset of a Euclidean space.

I've tried to tabulate these definitions, but I think it has ambiguities.

|  | Chart | Patch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| To | Other space | Manifold |
| From | Manifold | Other space |
| Homeomorphism | Yes | Maybe (Trying to remember if smoothness implies this) |
| Smooth | Maybe | Yes |
| Input Dimension | Any | 2 |
| Input is open | Yes | Yes |

What are the main differences between patches and charts?

Comment: Charts are just the inverses of coordinate patches. You should probably get one of the standrad books that define manifolds and read that rather than patching up from Wikipedia and such pages — much less pain will result.

Comment: Mathworld's definition of a patch is incorrect (there are lots of inaccuracies on Mathworld and unlike on Wikipedia they can't be corrected by the public; it's not reliable). A patch should, as Mariano says, be the inverse of a chart. So it should be a homeomorphism onto its image and a smooth patch should be a diffeomorphism onto its image.